# "Modern" OpenGL on Linux with GLFW

Tags: linux, windows, opengl, glfw

I can't get GLFW to work on Linux and Windows with the version of OpenGL I want to use (2.1 I think). It only provides gl definitions from the system headers, which are either for OpenGL 1.x, or GL/gl3.h, which doesn't seem to be available any more. I inferred from glfw's documentation that it automatically loads gl functions itself, but it seems I was wrong about this?

I want to write a portable game which uses OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android and a compatible subset of OpenGL 2.x on Linux and Windows. My development platform is Linux, I haven't tried compiling or testing anything on Windows yet. SDL has threading issues, and its OpenGL helper functions aren't suitable for OpenGL 2.x, so I chose glfw3.

GLFW also supports OpenGL ES 2.0 and Mesa does provide GLES/gl2.h so that might work. But I'm not sure whether Windows and all the Linux drivers support ES, especially NVidia, because it doesn't use Mesa; I'm worried it might force Linux to use software rendering, or fail altogether, on some hardware even where it supports OpenGL 2.0 (non-ES) or later.

Comment: There are a lot of wrong things in this question. "*OpenGL 3.x is obsolete*" No it isn't. "*appears to have no documentation about how it loads OpenGL functions and/or extensions*" That's because *it doesn't*. GLFW's job, just like SDL's job, is to create an OpenGL rendering context. How you talk to OpenGL is up to you, not GLFW, SDL, FreeGLUT, or anything else.

Comment: "*a version of OpenGL that's compatible with OpenGL ES 2.0?*" There's no such thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course there is, OpenGL ES 2.0 is largely a subset of OpenGL 2.1. Using some macro and/or template magic can do this (in the shader, as well as in C++ code). Also, there exist emulators of OpenGL ES 2.0 he can use, as well as the android emulator. Also, check http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/glx_create_context_es2_profile.txt

Comment: @user1095108: If you have to use "macro and/or template magic", then it's *not compatible*. Compatibility is something you get automatically; if you have to put a bunch of `#ifdef`s in your code, it's not really compatible.

Comment: OpenGL 3 is effectively obsolete because there is no GL/gl3.h in Linux any more (maybe there still is in WGL), and it's been removed from the Khronos registry too, so gl3w doesn't work.

Comment: I realise there are some more differences between ES and "full fat" than one being a subset of the other, but by choosing the right version I can minimise the hassle. [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming) is helpful eg in how to deal with ES requiring precision specifiers when full OGL doesn't use them.

Comment: @user1095108 I don't think the Android emulator supports OpenGL ES 2.0, only 1.1. But thanks for the link about EXT_create_context_es2_profile, I reckon I can use that to at least test whether I really need to use full OGL on PCs or whether they all support ES too. I've got enough different ones to test NVidia, AMD and NVidia on both Windows and Linux :) (but not Mac).

Comment: @NicolBolas GLFW's docs are misleading, they say don't include any GL headers before glfw3.h, but don't say that you **do** have to include the ones provided by the loader. Using a loader does get mentioned in the FAQ though. And SDL does load OpenGL functions for you if you ask it and are using a version it supports (which I'm not).

Comment: @realh: Whether or not gl3w works has *nothing* to do with whether GL 3.x is obsolete. The header is simply called `glcorearb.h` now, because obviously it includes GL 4.x stuff. It's simply a better description of its contents. And a [version of GL3W was updated to use it](https://github.com/shakesoda/gl3w).

Comment: @realh: "*whether they all support ES too*" They don't. NVIDIA's the only one who supports ES2 profiles.

Comment: @realh You are misinformed. The android emulator supports GLES 2 since last year!

Comment: Also, check this: http://www.mesa3d.org/opengles.html

Comment: I've run glxinfo on a few Linux boxes, and they all show GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile. That's with Mesa on Intel HD and AMD (open source) and also with the proprietary NVidia driver. I haven't tried nouveau, but I think it's also Mesa-based so should be the same. Nor have I tried fglrx (proprietary AMD driver). How can I test this on Windows? On Googling I found something that said AMD have started supporting GLES in Windows, but not NVidia.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Nicol Bolas' first comment was correct, GLFW doesn't include a GL function loader. I've got it working by using glLoadGen. It also seems to be necessary to call `glfwMakeContextCurrent` before `ogl_LoadFunctions` even if you haven't yet started any threads.